# Concatenating array elements with delimiter in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, delimiter

I want to join the elements of an array in MATLAB delimited by periods eg [1,2,3] into 1.2.3 (a string).

I tried doing `value = [sprintf('%d.',value{1:end-1}),value{end}];` but it doesn't work if there is only 1 element in the array eg. [1] turns into 1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fprintf('%d.', [1,2,3])
```

Only problem is this gives you one extra `.` at the end which you then need to manually remove

```
A = fprintf('%d.', [1,2,3])
A = A(1:end-1)
```